# \label{tab:a} does not show in listoftables but in listoffigures

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, spreadtab

I have a table made with spreadtab that does not show in the list of Tables but, instead, in the List of Figures. I don't know how to solve that.

this is a MWE that behaves wrong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{spreadtab} % loads 'xstring' automatically

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{ | l | c | l | }} 
\hline
@ Arbeitspaket        & @ Schätzung & @ Erklärung \\ 
\hline
@ Projektorganisation & 40            & @ \\
@ Projekt Analyse     & 5             & @ \\       
@ Lösungsvarianten    & 5             & @ \\      
@ Detailplanung       & 40            & @ \\       
@ Dokumentation       & 40            & @ \\
\hline \hline         
@ Total               & sum(b2:b5)    & @ \\ 
\hline
\end{spreadtab}
\caption{Zeitaufwand} \label{Zeitaufwand} 
\end{figure}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to get the table to show up in the list of tables?

Comment: A MWE doesn't need the bib - stuff, it seems unrelated to the `\listoftables issue

Comment: I've taken the liberty of simplifying your MWE considerably. Feel free to revert if you believe the bibliography-related code is, in fact, essential.

Answer (score 3):

you have put it in a figure `\begin{figure}[htbp]` so it is a figure, if you want it to be numbered and listed as a table, change `figure` to `table`

Comment: what a shame. true! And i tought its because of the tab: or fig: that its being placed in list of figures or list of tables...

Comment: @novski why a shame?